# Facebook sharing error in meta tag og

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree.
Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable.

Comment: Please paste your og meta tags code here

Comment: <head> <meta property="og:title" content="<%= "Amp Your Good"%>" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="<%= "'#{request.url}'" %>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<%= @drive.photo.url(:original) %>" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Amp Your Good" />  </head>

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you need to move your Open Graph Meta Tags under `<head>` tag from `<body>` tag.